# Using apa6, how do I get the date to appear on the title page after the authors

Tags: apa6, date

I've tried using:
\data{\today}

but no date is printed on the title page.

The only way I can get a date on the title page is by putting \today between the \begin{document} and \maketitle, i.e.:
\begin{document}
\today
\maketitle

This puts a date at the upper-left on the title page.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal example of code? What we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 3):

Use the macro `note`

```
\documentclass[]{apa6}

\title{Title}
\author{John Doe}
\affiliation{University}
\note{\today}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]